# Transcend Storeject portable HDD: what's the difference among 25A3, 25D3, 25M3 and 25H3P?

Tags: portable-harddrive

I'm looking for some portable hard disk, my friend recommended Transcend Storejet 2.5 inch models as they are shock resistance (or shock proof? i'm not sure about the term).

However searching on internet shows there are several models, 25A3, 25D3, 25M3, and 25H3P. Internet pages including Transcend ones seems only shows they "look" different, some with a cover over the casing, some not.

May I ask what's the difference, in sense of function/feature, other than the looking? does the cover make sense?